Progress bar for my Spring Batch Application - need to get number of Chunks or total number of items
I am trying to build a progress bar for my spring batch application and for that I am stuck at point.
I am unable to get the total number of items or total number of Chunks during runtime.
Can someone help? Is it supported by Spring Batch?
I checked and found out that the Spring Batch process total items in chunks based on the chunk size provided. So I'm unable to get the total Item Size or total chunk Size here.
